# Multiple contingent iteration lists through csv file - Python

Tags: python, csv, iteration

I'm on a Windows 7 x64 workstation running Python 2.7.3.

I have a CSV file containing rows of item IDs, with each row belonging to a group ID, like so:

```
GroupID ItemID
a   1
a   2
a   3
b   4
b   5
b   6
c   7
c   8
c   9
etc…
```

What I need to do is generate a list of tuples, wherein each tuple is a string of the GroupID and a list of each ItemID associated with the GroupID, like so:

```
[('a', [1, 2, 3]), ('b', [4, 5, 6]), ('c', [7 , 8, 9])]
```

So far I've thought of using a function or list to set conversion to de-duplicate the GroupID column, then doing some sort of comparison if statement on a second loop through. Could anyone give me some advice please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

> Make an iterator that returns consecutive keys and groups from the
>   iterable. The key is a function computing a key value for each
>   element. If not specified or is None, key defaults to an identity
>   function and returns the element unchanged. Generally, the iterable
>   needs to already be sorted on the same key function.

For example:

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

with open("test.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader) #Skip header
    data = groupby(reader, itemgetter(0))
    print([(key, [item for _, item in items]) for key, items in data])
```

We combine this with an [`operator.itemgetter()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to say we want to group by the first item in the row, then we use a nested [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) to extract the data we want.

Which gives us:

```
[('a', ['1', '2', '3']), ('b', ['4', '5', '6']), ('c', ['7', '8', '9'])]
```

Naturally, unless you *need* a list, it is better to use a generator expression here to do the operation lazily. (We use a list comprehension here to get nice output).

Note that I assume your file is comma separated like you say, not as shown in your example. If it's tab separated, use `csv.reader(file, dialect=csv.excel_tab)` to parse it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If the grouping key is sequential, then something like:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('b', 5)]

grouped = [(k, map(itemgetter(1), g)) for k, g in groupby(data, itemgetter(0))]
# [('a', [1, 2]), ('b', [3, 5])]
```

Otherwise, use a `collections.defaultdict`.

Comment: Note that using `map()` and an `operator.itemgetter()` is hugely less readable and also significantly (⅓ in my tests) slower than using a list comprehension and indexing or tuple unpacking and throwing away the first part (`[i[1] for i in g]` or `[i for _, i in g]` respectively).

Comment: @Lattyware "hugely less readable" I dispute, but otherwise - fair enough point.